# Set Text property of Label to variable value in Power Apps

Tags: powerapps

I have code in OnStart property of an App that stores values of the Users that use the App like first name. I want to use the value of that variable as the text of a label but it’s just showing the name of the variable instead of the value that’s stored in the variable. For example, I have a variable named “varUserName” that stores the name “Chad”. Instead of showing “Chad” it shows “varUserName”. I started running Onstart manually and I see that the variable has been initialized because it’s on the Variable list of Power Apps with a value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you have the `Text` property of the label set to `"varUserName"` (with quotes) instead of `varUserName` (without quotes). Try removing the quotes. Note that you need to set this from the "Advanced" tab of the label, NOT the "Properties" tab.

Comment: This was it. For some reason if I edit the text field in the properties window it adds quotes. If the edit it in the formula bar (fx) it doesn’t add quotes

Answer (score 0):

Put your variable in the label's text property. Please note that anything between double quotes is identified as a text by powerapps. To identify it as a variable, lose the double quotes.

Additionally, I would save the entire profile of the user in the onstart event. Like Set(CurrentUser,MyProfile());

This way, I can use the CurrentUser.DisplayName to get the name, CurrentUser.Mail to get the email and so on.

Answer (score 0):

To get the logged-in user's properties, place the following `OnStart` of the app:

**Using PowerApps built-in user functionality**

```
Set(varUser, User());
```

- This gives you `varUser.Email`, `varUser.FullName` and `varUser.Image`

**Using the Office365Users.SearchUsersV2 Connector**

```
Set(
    varO365User, 
    Office365Users.SearchUserV2(
        {
            searchTerm: User().FullName
        }
    ).value
)
```

- This gives you MANY more properties, but does not natively provide `.Image`.

**Illustration:**

[image]